# echarts reduce space between ticks

Tags: echarts

I have this simple bar chart:

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
      type: 'bar'
    }
  ]
};
```

How can I reduce the space the y axis (or xaxsis) takes up?

My current solution is:

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  grid : {
     width : 100,
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
      type: 'bar'
    }
  ]
};
```

However, the resulting display is still as wide, just the image itself has been reduced. This is not really what I am looking for as I want the resulting image to not be larger than the graph. Reducing the image size (i.e., by export to svg), reduces the space too much and the ticks are not visible anymore.

I.e., I want the graph to be not as wide or high.

Comment: I don't really understand your issue. If it's about sizing, your solution seems quite good (using `grid`'s width & height). Otherwise you could let the chart full size and just reduce the size of the <div> it's in. If it's about reducing blank space around the chart (so that it fills the space), I would suggest setting `grid`'s top, bottom, left and right parameters to 0%.

Comment: the issue is, that exporting the generated image to an SVG requires using an svg image being significantly larger (width) than the generate graph. As soon as the svg width is adjusted the underlying grid gets squished as well.